# Trigger select change event and callback when done with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a hierarchy of filters where each filter in the hierarchy is dynamically put on the page from ajax calls of the parent filter. (ajax calls return partial views with the next step in the hierarchy and it's slowly animated on the page to look smooth)

For example the first filter on the page is region. Once you select a region an ajax call is made that returns a partial view of countries. Once a country is selected an ajax call is made that returns a partial view of states, etc.

Now I allow for saving filters for later retrieval. This is producing a problem when a filter is selected. I'm able to select the region radio buttons and trigger it's change() event via code, but I'm lost after that because I can't just instantly select the country radio button in code because it doesn't exist until the ajax call from regions comes backs. When I trigger the change() event for regions is there a way to have a callback that is fired once that change() event is finished being called so I can then continue to chain select the other options with code?

I think I could put global flags in each levels ajax.done() but how would I loop in my filter select event allowing everything to not seem like it's locked up checking for each flag before selecting the next level in code?

Currently I have:

```
$("input:radio[name=regions][value=USA]").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Comment: where's the filter code that needs to be adjusted? Question is a bit abstract without some code examples

Comment: How about adding each next step to the success callback of the previous - so, in the success function for the first AJAX call, populate the new filters, retrieve the next filter from local storage/cookie, apply it and trigger the next AJAX call?